# How can i add text or another image under this super aligned image : HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am not very good with coding. I grabbed this code from a google search, as I wanted to make a very simple splash page which is responsive.

The thing is that I want to put another image under the one in the , but this next image, gets centered on top of the first one.

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Best regards
Anders

theme.css:

```
<style type="text/css">

#bg {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:-50%;
width:200%;
height:75%;
}
#bg img {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
min-width:30%;
min-height:30%;
}

</style>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Childhood Projects</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="bg">
<img src="cp.gif" id="back1" alt="Childhood Projects" width="42"/>
</div>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot
-Anders

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
#bg {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:-50%;
width:200%;
height:75%;
}
#bg img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible do not use `position: absolute;`.

Also `margin:auto;` will center every image horizontally so you can remove it or set to pixel based value.

```
#bg img {
  position:static;
  margin:20px;
  min-width:30%;
  min-height:30%;
}
```